# Login form and registration PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I've recently started dealing with form validation and login/registering. But, I have a problem, when I click on login button with existing user and password, I want to be transfered to the same page (login page) or start page with message: "You have successfully logged in". I don't know how to do that. I have among others, two php files, **login.php**:

```
 if (loggedin()) {
        $firstname = getuserfield('firstname');
        $surname = getuserfield('surname');
        echo 'You\'re logged in, '.$firstname.' '.$surname.'. <a href="logout.php">Log       out </a><br>';
    } else {
    include 'loginform.inc.php';

    }
```

and **loginform.inc.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password_hash = md5($password);
    if (!empty($username)&&!empty($password)) {
        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND `password`='".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."'";
        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if ($query_num_rows==0) {
            ?> <div id = "a5"> <?php echo 'No such combination of username and password' ?> </div>; <?php
            } else if ($query_num_rows==1){
            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;

            header('Location: login.php');
            }
            }
    } else {
?> <div id="a"> <?php echo 'Please enter username and password!' ?> </div>
```

Comment: why don't you redirect to success page after validating credentials of the user??? and on success page, just check if session is set or not!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use some more advanced login. The login form I used works perfect and is easy to understand and work with. Visit this [login form](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) for the login I used. It's also easy to convert to OO if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

**Method : 1**

You can include the `loginform.inc.php` after successfully login on `login.php` like this

```
if (loggedin()) {
        $firstname = getuserfield('firstname');
        $surname = getuserfield('surname');
        echo 'You\'re logged in, '.$firstname.' '.$surname.'. <a href="logout.php">Log       out </a><br>';
         include 'loginform.inc.php'; // include here after successfully login
    } else {
    include 'loginform.inc.php';

    }
```

**Method : 2**

you can store your success message in a SESSION variable and transfer header on `loginform.inc.php`. and then you can print your session on `loginform.inc.php` page.

**login.php:**

```
session_start();
 if (loggedin()) {
            $firstname = getuserfield('firstname');
            $surname = getuserfield('surname');
            $_SESSION['msg_text'] = 'You\'re logged in, '.$firstname.' '.$surname.'. <a href="logout.php">Log       out </a><br>'; // set a session variable

               header("location:loginform.inc.php"); // transfer header on the loginform.inc.php page
               exit;

        } else {
        include 'loginform.inc.php';

        }
```